# Equivalent of [​tag​:​X​] but allow linking to a tag on any SE site

Tags: feature-request, tags, chat, markdown, tag-links

If I enter `[tag:X]` on meta.stackoverflow.com, it is rendered as a link to tag `X` on stackoverflow.com.

Similarly if I post `[tag:X]` on chat, it is interpreted as a link to that tag on the SE site associated with that chat room.

I would like to be able to link to a tag on any SE site, not necessarily the one associated with that chat room.  E.g. I would like to be able to include [python](/questions/tagged/python) in a chat message associated with another site such as [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com) and have it link to the corresponding tag wiki in stackoverflow (not unix.)

As far as I know the closest you can get at the moment is `<kbd>` elements inside links (e.g. 
[<kbd>python</kbd>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)) but that does not work in chat and does match the style of "real" taglinks.

Any chance of extending the markup syntax to permit this?

Comment: Note that `[meta-tag:X]` exists as well.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem exceptionally useful in the general case. Why would the average person need to link to a tag on another site? It also seems like it would be confusing; seeing Programmers-specific tags on SO would be bad without an obvious indicator of "no, these aren't real tags here, don't try to use them in that burning question of yours".

Comment: Because I want to discuss a SO tag on another programming-related SE site, and the tag has counterparts on both sites (as it is on-topic for both.)

Comment: [when there are posts like this](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277/should-tags-be-written-in-the-plural-or-singular-form)